# Using Ubuntu 20.04 with zfs, new install, how can I add a second drive to create a mirror (raid 1 ?)

Tags: hard-drive, raid, zfs

Just installed 20.04 using ZFS on a system containing 2 1T HHDs. the installer creates 2 pools for /boot and for root. Unfortunately, the installer doesn't seem to know about raid or zraid. So how can I set up the 2nd HDD as a mirror, preferably for both bpool and rpool ?

Does -

```
# zpool add mirror bpool /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
# zpool add mirror rpool /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2
```

look reasonable ?

And will ZFS automatically re-silver the mirror ?

Thanks for any help,
Gene

Comment: And, of course, I'm aware that using /dev/disk/by-id/... is more reliable than /dev/sd??

Answer (score 1):

No, the incantation you want is:

```
zpool attach bpool /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
zpool attach rpool /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2
```

Comment: So does that create a mirror (raid 1) ? It looks like one winds up with a pool "bpool" across 2 drives and "rpool" across 2 drives each with twice the storage capacity rather than mirrored pools.  Just trying to be sure before I commit.

Comment: Ok. Ignore comment above. A little further research (after you pointed me in the right direction) says attach is indeed the way to go, thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Using add instead of attach is a common mistake.

Comment: One last thing... is it necessary to do "installgrub" or some equivalent on /dev/sdb after resilvering ?  Thanks again.

Comment: Probably, on a legacy BIOS setup.