# Procedure: How to create mirror RAID via ZFS on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: partitioning, raid, zfs, 20.10

I have two 1TB disks. I ran a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.10 using encryption + ZFS, which installed to /dev/sda.

It created the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model:
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 917DAC1E-06D8-479B-AAC6-43FB711931BD

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096    1054719    1050624  513M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1054720    5249023    4194304    2G Linux swap
/dev/sda4  5249024    9443327    4194304    2G Solaris boot
/dev/sda5  9443328 1953525134 1944081807  927G Solaris root


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model:
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4176D618-E056-4905-BCFE-7ACA909134CD
```

Lsblck shows:

```
sda                          931.5G
├─sda1                           1M
├─sda2           vfat          513M /boot/efi
├─sda3           crypto_LUKS     2G
│ └─cryptoswap   swap            2G [SWAP]
├─sda4           zfs_member      2G                              bpool
└─sda5           zfs_member    927G                              rpool
sdb                          931.5G
sr0                           1024M
zd0              crypto_LUKS   500M
└─keystore-rpool ext4          484M /run/keystore/rpool          keystore-rpool
```

Is there a way to turn /dev/sdb into a proper mirror of /dev/sda using RAIDZ with ZFS? I've found some notes and tutorials that seem to give parts (like [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238363/using-ubuntu-20-04-with-zfs-new-install-how-can-i-add-a-second-drive-to-create), but I think it would already need partitions configured and wouldn't be a drive mirror, or maybe having a full drive mirror configuration wouldn't be possible with this ZFS+Encryption fresh installation?

Comment: Hi Bart, would you consider un-marking the answer below as accepted so I can post another bounty on your question, please? The answer doesn't directly solve your (and my) issue.

Comment: @TomPaine Okey dokey.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but i don't think you can convert installed system like that into zfs mirror and use the entire disk. The install is divided into few steps, this was for the Ubuntu 18 but this is probably very similar to 20.04.

EFI check

Preparations

Install the ZFS module in the live (loaded) kernel

Find the disks

Prepare the disk(s)

Install Ubuntu

Chroot and prepare the jail

Install ZFS 0.8 packages

Install and configure the bootloader

Cloning the EFI partition

Configure the boot pool import, and remaining settings

Found a very detailed guide which follows the steps in a copy paste setup.  https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/Installing-Ubuntu-on-a-ZFS-root-with-encryption-and-mirroring/.

I hope this helps you. I don't think that the setup is trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I'm afraid I can't award the bounty as it doesn't address the original question of taking a default guided installation and mirroring the partitions/pools.